# How to share a common database for many users or allow few Pc to access my database by using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For my assignment I have to make a application for our department's letter handling section. In our department there are

- Head of the Department
- Lecturers
- Non-academic staff
- Students

Letters for all of them are firstly received to office clerk. so I needed to make an app to make easier the clerk work.

1. The clerk categorize the letters and upload their pdf to database.
2. Then other above members can access them from their personal PC in
   their office.

All the office PC are connected to the local area network.

For this I need to use Visual studio.
I have fundamental knowledge about c# and visual studio.
So any one can give me the clue to how to do this  ....

Comment: I would download SQL Server Express from MSDN (free).  It will allow a database to be shared between users.  Plenty of sample code on web to interface with c#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server (SQL Server Express - free version). Instal it in your local server. Them follow the steps from this link to create the connection in visual studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx

You can them use dataadapter to make your interaction with database a lot easier. Check this link: http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/dataadapter-sqlserver.htm